# Do the functions, which do not approach infinity, also have limiting values?

Tags: limits

[image]

The above graph shows that its $y$ value is always $\pm4$ when $x$ approaches $\pm\infty$.

So, what would be the value of, say, $\lim\limits_{x \to 4} f(x)$?

Is it $4$? Explain why.

**Do the functions, which do not approach infinity, have limiting values?**

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense to me. Of course $\lim_{x\to 4} f(x)=4$, since $f$ approaches $4$ as $x\to 4$. What does that have to do with infinity, though?

Comment: @JackM, [Can You Name a Country?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRh1zXFKC_o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for a continuos function

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$$

and the given function is continuous at $x=4$.

We can't say nothing for the limit at infinity since we have not sufficient information.

Comment: @yahoo.com Yes for the first question you are correct even if you have expressed the definition in a naive way, the idea is what you had.

Comment: @yahoo.com More precisely we say that the function approaches $2$ closer and closer as $x$ becomes larger and larger.